# Python Bot creating Empty File

Tags: python, openai-api

I created a custom python code for content creation using OpenAI API.

This is the code :

```
from openai import OpenAI
import time
import os
import csv
import logging

# Your OpenAI API key
api_key = "myapikey"

client = OpenAI(api_key=api_key)

# Path to the CSV file containing city names
csv_file = "city.csv"

# Directory where generated content files will be saved
output_directory = "output/"

# Initialize the OpenAI API client

# Configure logging to save error messages
logging.basicConfig(
    filename="error_log.txt",
    level=logging.ERROR,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
)

# Read city names from the CSV file
def read_city_names_from_csv(file_path):
    city_names = []
    with open(file_path, "r") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row:
                city_names.append(row[0])
    return city_names

# Generate content for a given city name and save it to a file
def generate_and_save_content(city_name):
    prompt_template = (
        "Prompt.... {city_name} "
     )

    messages = [
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt_template.format(city_name=city_name)},
    ]

    try:
        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=messages,
            max_tokens=3000
        )
        choices = response.choices
        chat_completion = choices[0]
        content = chat_completion.message.content
        output_file = os.path.join(output_directory, city_name + ".txt")
        with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(content)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"Error generating content for {city_name}: {str(e)}"
        print(error_message)
        logging.error(error_message)
        return False

# Main function
def main():
    # Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
        os.makedirs(output_directory)

    city_names = read_city_names_from_csv(csv_file)
    successful_chats = 0
    unsuccessful_chats = 0

    for city_name in city_names:
        print(f"Generating content for {city_name}...")
        success = generate_and_save_content(city_name)
        if success:
            successful_chats += 1
        else:
            unsuccessful_chats += 1

        # Add a delay to avoid API rate limits
        time.sleep(2)

    print("Content generation completed.")
    print(f"Successful chats: {successful_chats}")
    print(f"Unsuccessful chats: {unsuccessful_chats}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When i created the bot, everthing was fine, but now when i want to use it, it will create the output file but without any content, 0 byte size, without any file format.

I changed the code to get the responds on the CMD, and i get it without any problem, also i checked the API Key and it is live. Can you help me to fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see in your code, you're using a relative path for writing the csv file, this usually leads to unexpected behavior. Maybe you're creating the file but it is not in the desired location.

One approach, is using the **os** module to get the full path for wherever you're running the code from:

```py
from os import getcwd

csv_path = f"{getcwd()}/city.csv"
output_path = f"{getcwd()}/output"
```

I think this enough for you to modify your code, if you need help with it, please let me know and I'll edit this answer :)

Comment: City.csv is input, and it is working well, as in the csv we have title of content, the bot will get the title, and we will have the output file with the name that came from the csv file. so it is not about the csv

Comment: Yes, I understood that you're able to read the file, but when saving the output is not doing so. Have you tried using a full path when writing?

Comment: yes , tried and same problem

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and it works well.
I think you have a problem in running the bot.

Please try the bot with command "python your_bot.py"
And confirm city.csv 's location.
Please feel free to ask. I can help you.

Comment: dont work mate, the problem is with the output.txt file, dont have any problem with csv

Comment: Can you share your project structure in absolute path?

Comment: Bot is working perfectly, i changed it, now instead of generate a unique output for each respond, it will generate all response in the end of the process in one txt file. the file will generate without any problem. after days of change and edits, the previous approach didnt work and all files will be empty, even with other formats.

Comment: I see what you mean.
Please try file.close() after writing content.

Comment: And check if there are any conflicts in the city names.

Comment: And there may be a problem in using openai api.
There are limits(rate limit. i.e. 3 api calls per 1 minute) in OpenAI api. Your api key is free or premium?